# Interaction between aws cli, crontab and user privileges

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-s3, cron, aws-cli

I have a ec2 that's supposed to sync to s3 every 5mins, so I installed awscli under sudo, entered my credentials in using aws configure. I then created a shell script at /home/ubuntu/ with entries such as:

```
 aws s3 cp s3://datasets/B3 /home/ubuntu/data/B3 --recursive
```

And in the sudo crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/s3syncer.sh
```

But it doesn't sync. I've had this issue before so I tried:

```
/home/ubuntu/.aws aws s3 cp s3://datasets/B3 /home/ubuntu/data/B3 --recursive
/usr/bin/aws aws s3 cp s3://datasets/B3 /home/ubuntu/data/B3 --recursive
```

And it seems /usr/bin/aws is now working....
Also when I try 'aws configure' as user ubuntu, it says Incorrect permissions.

1. How are permissions for editing aws configure determined? Did installing it with sudo make it so I can't edit configure as ubuntu?
2. How does /usr/bin/aws change the execution of aws s3 syncing?
3. How are commands executed from sudo v ubuntu crontabs different?

Thanks, some these are general linux questions...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did `sudo aws configure`, it did not change your `$HOME` directory. Therefore, it stored your creds in the "wrong" place (`/home/ubuntu` instead of `/root`), and you have trouble getting them from the ubuntu user.

You need to run `sudo -H aws configure` so it has the `/root` home directory when configuring. Then your `/usr/bin/aws` example will work.

You may also want to delete the root-owned creds in your ubuntu home directory.

Oh, to answer your questions:

1) There is nothing special about AWS, it's all because you used `sudo` without `-H`, and it wrote creds to the wrong place.

2) I'm not sure what this question is asking?

3) Root often has different environment vars than normal users. For example, `/usr/local/bin` is not always in the root path for some distros. It's best to get in the habit of specifying the full path.